# Dash and custom CSS to change image from light to dark inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash app. I am trying to change logo from light to dark on hover of the anchor tag.
Currently it is only working when hover the image but it does not change when hover the anchor tag.

**custom-style.css**

```
.logo{
    content:url("/assets/image_light.jpg");
}

.logo:hover{
    content:url("/assets/image_dark.jpg");
}
```

**app.py**

```
html.A(
  dbc.Row(
    children=[
      dbc.Col(
        children=html.Img(className="logo", height=20, width=20)
      ),
      dbc.Col(
        dbc.NavbarBrand("My Dashboard", className="ms-2")
      ),
   ],
   align="center",
   className="g-0",
  ),
  href="http://localhost",
  style={"textDecoration": "none"},
),
```

I tried adding a:hover(next to .logo:hover) but it does not worked.

I am newbie in css and html, Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was using `a:hover .logo:hover`. Solved by using this

```
a:hover .logo{
   content:url("/assets/image_dark.jpg");  
}
```